# How to match this table cell using Espresso?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-testing, hamcrest, android-espresso

I need to match the view which is highlighted by a red rectangle. Which Espresso expression should I write for it?

[image]

This is a table layout, all cells are instances of TextView. There are no unique IDs for cell views. The view of interest may or may not have text inside. All I know is that this view is always sitting below the "Food Group" cell.

Any clues would be welcome.

Comment: As a basic idea: I would try to write a matcher isInTableAtPosition(final Matcher<View> tableMatcher, int row, int column). You can match view if its parent is a TableRow and if it is the <col>th child of that row and then check if that TableRow is the <row>th child of the table matched by tableMatcher. Not sure about the internals of a TableLayout, it probably has a more complex internal layout, but that can be seen deducted from view hierarchy and Android sources.

Comment: Sounds like an idea to check, thanks!

Comment: What kind of assertion are you trying to write? When you say "The view of interest may or may not have text inside", do you know for a given test case whether that view will have text and what it should be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the test I would write in your case.

```
public void testCellBelowFoodGroup() {
    getActivity();
    onView(
        allOf(
            isDescendantOfA(isAssignableFrom(TableLayout.class)),
            isInRowBelow(withText("Food Group")),
            hasChildPosition(0)
            )
    ).check(matches(withText("TEXT TO BE FOUND")));
}
```

So, we are looking for a view inside a given TableLayout, that is in a row below the "Food Group" text, and that is the leftmost element of the row. Then we can do whatever we want with that view, e.g. check its text.

`isInRowBelow` and `hasChildPosition` are not provided by Espresso, they are custom methods, as is usual when testing with Espresso: you are encouraged to create your own view assertions and view matchers.

Here is the implementation.

```
static Matcher<View> isInRowBelow(final Matcher<View> viewInRowAbove) {
    checkNotNull(viewInRowAbove);
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>(){

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("is below a: ");
            viewInRowAbove.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            // Find the current row
            ViewParent viewParent = view.getParent();
            if (!(viewParent instanceof TableRow)) {
                return false;
            }
            TableRow currentRow = (TableRow) viewParent;
            // Find the row above
            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) currentRow.getParent();
            int currentRowIndex = table.indexOfChild(currentRow);
            if (currentRowIndex < 1) {
                return false;
            }
            TableRow rowAbove = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(currentRowIndex - 1);
            // Does the row above contains at least one view that matches viewInRowAbove?
            for(int i = 0 ; i < rowAbove.getChildCount() ; i++) {
                if (viewInRowAbove.matches(rowAbove.getChildAt(i))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }};
}

static Matcher<View> hasChildPosition(final int i) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>(){

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("is child #" + i);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            ViewParent viewParent = view.getParent();
            if (!(viewParent instanceof ViewGroup)) {
                return false;
            }
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) viewParent;
            return (viewGroup.indexOfChild(view) == i);
        }};
}
```

The full source code can be downloaded from https://github.com/acontal/android-stackoverflow-espresso-match_table_cell